# AJAX Form Submission Not Querying PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Trying to use AJAX to submit form data to a PHP file. Everything in the code seems to work except for a call to the PHP file.

I setup a Java Alert() on the PHP file and it never alerts.

I am sure it is an issue with the AJAX code but I don't know it well enough to figure out what is going wrong.

The AJAX Call:

```
$(document).on('click','.addItem',function(){

// Add Item To Merchant
    var el = this;
    var id = this.id;  

    var splitid = id.split("_");

    // Add id's
    var addid = splitid[1];  // Merchant ID
    var additem = splitid[2];  // Item ID

    // AJAX Request
    $.ajax({
        url: "jquery/addItem.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { mid : addid , iit : additem },
        success: function(response){

            // Removing row from HTML Table
            $(el).closest('tr').css('background','tomato');
            $(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(300, function(){      
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }
    });
```

});

The HTML Form Call Within a Table:

```
<span class='addItem' id='addItem_<?php echo $m; ?>_<?php echo $list['id']; ?>' >Add Item</span>
```

Ok Simple PHP code that it calls to with some alerts for testing:

```
    <?php
require_once("../includes/constants.php");
require_once("../includes/functions.php");

$iid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'iit', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  // Item ID
$mid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mid', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  // Merchant ID

$slot = 0;

$slot = getMerchSlot($mid);
    ?>
    <script>
        alert ("Slot Value: <?php echo $slot; ?>");
        </script>
    <?php           
                $result = $pdoConn->query("INSERT INTO merchantlist (merchantid, item, slot) 
                                                            VALUES 
                                                        ('$mid', '$iid', '$slot') ");

                    if ($result) {
                        ?>
                        <script>
                            alert("Looks like it worked");
                        </script>
                        <?php                       
                    } 

                echo 1;


?>
```

Comment: can you show backend code?

Comment: java and javascript aren't the same thing

Comment: where is ur form code ???